# Adding of a edge in a graph using adjaceny-list in c++

Tags: c++, vector, graph, adjacency-list

This how i've defined my graph,it is specific to the problem i'm dealing with.

```
    class Vertex;

    Class Edge
    {
        Vertex *org;
        Vertex *dest;
        int traverse_time;
    };
    struct Vertex{
        int id;
        vector<Edge> edges;
        int weight;
    };
    struct Graph{
        vector<Vertex> vertices;
    };
```

This is how i've been adding vertices

`Graph* g1=new Graph;
Vertex* newvertex = addVertex(0);
graph1->vertices.push_back(*newvertex);`

The add Vertex function works fine but still if you need

```
Vertex* addVertex(int id){
Vertex*newVertex = new Vertex;
newVertex->id=id;
newVertex->weight=0;
return newVertex;}
```

I'm having a problem when i try to add edges to these vertices.This how i've been doing

```
org=&(g1->vertices[0]);
dest=&(g1->vertices[1]);
Edge* newedge=addRoad(org,dest,1);
org->edges.push_back(*newedge);
dest->edges.push_back(*newedge);
```

The addEdge function is defined as follows:

```
Edge* addedge(Vertex* j_id1,Vertex* j_id2,int t)
{
    Edge *newedge =new Edge;
    newedge->org=j_id1;
    newedge->dest=j_id2;
    newedge->traverse_time=t;
    return newedge;
}
```

The function stops working just before `org->edges.push_back(*newedge);`

Comment: `Vertex* new = addVertex(0);` well that shouldn't compile. Also what do you mean by stops working?

Comment: My bad,that was `Vertex *newvertex=addVertex(0);` Program exits when try to insert a edge.

Comment: Is there an error given?

Comment: No there was no error given. The exe files stops working when i try to add an edge to my graph.I commented out the adding edge part and rest of program works fine.

Comment: This line is the problem `org->edges.push_back(*newedge);` i guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One must be careful when working with pointers to elements of vectors, because when a vector is resized (calling `push_back` when it has no reserve space left), there is no guarantee that each element will still occupy the same memory address.

Instead, use *indices*.

```
struct Edge
{
    unsigned A, B;  // indices
    int weight;

    Edge(unsigned a, unsigned b, int w) : A(a), B(b), weight(w) {}
};
struct Vertex
{
    int id, weight;
    vector<unsigned> edges;  // edge indices

    Vertex(int i, int w) : id(i), weight(w) {}
};

struct Graph
{
    vector<Vertex> vertices;
    vector<Edge>   edges;   // use a vector for edges too for EZ deallocation

    // make the relevant functions members

    void addVertex(int id)
    {
        // in-place constructor
        vertices.emplace_back(id, 0);
    }
    bool addEdge(unsigned v1, unsigned v2, int t)
    { 
        // check if indices are valid
        if (v1 >= vertices.size() && v2 >= vertices.size())
            return false;

        unsigned newindex = edges.size();  // index of new edge
        edges.emplace_back(v1, v2, t);

        // add this edge's index to endpoints
        vertices[v1].edges.push_back(newindex);
        vertices[v2].edges.push_back(newindex);

        return true;
    }
};
```

Lots of other possible improvements, but this should at least fix the memory access problem.

Answer (score 0):

Change `Edge` from a class to a struct, or make it's properties public, classes have private members as standard whereas structs have public.

Comment: I changed `Edge` into `struct` but still .exe stops working when i try to add an edge

Comment: Try launching the the executable from the command line, it will stay open to show you the error

Comment: this is what i got `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x000055a75ac0c3e8 ***
Aborted (core dumped)`

Answer (score -1):

Your design has couple of flaws, why you are defining Edge as:

```
Class Edge
{
    Vertex *org;
    Vertex *dest;
    int traverse_time;
};
```

Relationship between Vertexes should be clear if one has its neighbors defined as adjacency-list i.e:

```
Class Cost
{
    int traverse_time;
};

struct Vertex{
    int id;
    map<shared_ptr<Vertex>, Cost> neighbours;
    int weight;
};
```

Next, when you add vertexes in your solution you write:

```
Edge* newedge=addRoad(org,dest,1);
org->edges.push_back(*newedge);
dest->edges.push_back(*newedge);
```

This don't make much sense for dest vertex as your edge is from orig -> dest.

Comment: Alright, but this is a undirected weighted graph.So i added edge to both org and dest.Is that approach correct ?

Comment: The whole point of adjacency-list is that it creates relationship, you don't have to create Edge class. The fact that it is undirected don't change what has been said, and weighted, means it just has some costs between edges.